# Node scripts to run powershell commands

Tags: node.js, mongodb, powershell, npm, nodemon

Currently when developing locally I run my MongoDB and start Nodemon. I do this in vscode terminals but I never remember the commands so I have a txt file that I copy/paste from every time. I was wondering if it's possible to set a script in my package.json that I could call to run these for me.

I've tried to use the answer from [how to execute powershell ps1 scripts from package.json "scripts"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353836/how-to-execute-powershell-ps1-scripts-from-package-json-scripts) as an example but since I'm not able to figure it out. The two things I'm currently doing are:

To start MongoDB

```
& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe'
```

To start Nodemon. I also set the node_env to development here

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"
nodemon server/server.js
```

I've been doing it the current way for months, so it isn't that big of a deal. I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to start these up without copy/pasting the commands.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you ***don't*** actually launch the `mongod` process with each application start ( and especially restart ). Instead it's *far more sane* to simply spawn this process ( preferably in a background process ) **once**, and possibly preferably on your computer startup as a service. Unless you really have some need for "multiple instances" ( and I don't see any `--dpbath` or `--port` options, so you likely do not ) then that's what you should be doing. Consult the documentation on installing as a Windows Service instead.

Comment: For reference: [Configure a Windows Service for MongoDB Community Edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition)

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this question and using the question you linked this was my solution:

Create two scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "powershell": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./run_dev.ps1",
  "start": "nodemon server/server.js"
}
```

Create `run_dev.ps1` in the same directory as my `package.json` with the following line:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"; npm start
```

So when you run `npm run powershell` it'll run the powershell file and nodemon all within the same terminal with the env correctly set - running fine within my VS Code terminal. I know the question's old but hopefully this helps others that found their way here.