# How to run multiple PowerShell commands with package.json scripts

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I have the following script definition "debug-windows" in my `package.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "debug-windows": "$env:NODE_ENV=\"dev\"; node src/dequeue.js"
    }
}
```

Which I run using `npm run debug-windows` and I get the error:

```bsh
> servicebus-timeout@1.0.0 debug-windows C:\myapp
> $env:NODE_ENV="dev"; node src/dequeue.js

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! servicebus-timeout@1.0.0 debug-windows-test: `$env:NODE_ENV="dev"; node src/dequeue.js`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the servicebus-timeout@1.0.0 debug-windows-test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-27T16_29_32_585Z-debug.log
```

If I run the same command directly on PowerShell it succeeds:

```bsh
PS C:\myapp> $env:NODE_ENV="dev"; node src/dequeue.js
Waiting for messages: Mon Apr 27 2020 13:24:06 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time checking the npm docs and found out the problem. `npm-run-script` runs CMD on Windows, and not PowerShell.

The solution was to separate the commands using `&` and the appropriate `set` to define session variables:

```
"debug-windows": "set NODE_ENV=dev & node src/dequeue.js"
```

I have no need for npm to use PowerShell, it's just that I thought it was doing so.

If one wants to run PowerShell for other reasons, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46353836/3231778) which has a lot of options.

Documentation on [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By
>   default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it
>   is the cmd.exe. The actual shell referred to by /bin/sh also depends
>   on the system. As of npm@5.1.0 you can customize the shell with the
>   script-shell configuration.

Comment: For a cross-platform solution (i.e. for windows `cmd` and _*nix_ `sh`) utilize [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Comment: @RobC I didn't know about that one! I will certainly try it out for `package.json` and other automations.